# Is diagonalizability a local property?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}_+$. Consider a $n\times n$-matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$ with entries in $R$. A diagonal matrix is defined obviously. We can define several notions about diagonalizability (for some prime $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq R$):

1. $A$ is *diagonalizable in $R$*: if there exists an $n\times n$-matrix $P$ with entires in $R$ such that $\det(P)\in R^\times$ and $PAP^{-1}$ is diagonal;
2. $A$ is *diagonalizable in $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$*: consider $A$ as a matrix over $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and similarly defined;
3. $A$ is *diagonalizable in $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$*: similarly defined;
4. $A$ is *diagonalizable in $\overline{\kappa(\mathfrak{p})}$*: similarly defined, where we consider an algebraic closure.

Obviously $(1)\implies(2)\implies(3)\implies(4)$. Moreover $(4)$ has the minimal polynomial criterion. I have two observations:

- (2) is an open condition on $\mathfrak{p}$: the primes $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $A$ is diagonalizable in $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ form an open subset of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$;
- (4) is a *constructible condition* on $\mathfrak{p}$: the primes $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $(4)$ holds form a constructible subset. This is seen from the morphism, whose image is where $(4)$ holds
  $$\mathrm{GL}_n\times\mathbb{A}^n\to \mathbb{A}^{n\times n},\quad P,\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n\mapsto P\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1\\&\ddots\\&&\lambda_n\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}. $$

I do not expect either $(3)\implies(2)$ or $(4)\implies(3)$, though my intuition of local diagonalizability is $(4)$. My question is about $(2)\implies(1)$. For the title I mean the following.

> If $A$ is diagonalizable in $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for all primes $\mathfrak{p}$, can we claim that $A$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: I'm confused: if $A=1$ is the identity and $R=\mathbb{C}$, there's no Euclidean neighborhood of $1$ consisting only of diagonal matrices, because each neighborhood will contain a matrix equal to $1$ plus a nonzero off-diagonal term, which is not diagonalizable. So in particular, there's no such neighborhood in the Zariski topology, and I believe (2) is not open, merely constructible.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by Spec($A$).

Comment: @DaveBenson That is Spec(R), just edited.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I do not think this is a counterexample. Your example satisfies (1) since $A$ is the identity matrix (is this what in your mind?), and then (1) is true for any $R$. Then (2) holds for every prime of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen if you believe this locus is constructible, then it is actually open since it is also stable under generalisation \[Tag [0903](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0903)\]: if $\mathfrak p \subseteq \mathfrak q$ and $A_{\mathfrak q}$ is diagonalisable, then $A_{\mathfrak p}$ is diagonalisable as well. I think you might be confusing stalks with fibres, but it was already noted that (4) is only constructible.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Aaaaaaah! **The matrix is fixed** in the whole question, the thing that is made to vary is where it is considered! OK, I misread the question, but, considering the upvotes my comment got, I'm not the only one who was confused (and the title of the question is especially confusing). This deserves at least a warning or clarification.

Comment: (I mean, I thought the question was about the openness or constructibility of the set of diagonalizable matrices, with various conditions on diagonalizability, inside all matrices. So, yes, I misread, but I still think this is very confusing.)

Comment: To make sense of items 2, 3, 4, would you introduce $\mathfrak{p}$ somewhere? and specify "for all $\mathfrak{p}$" or "for the given $\mathfrak{p}$, or something.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a simple counterexample (simplified and generalised after Mohan's comment): let $R$ be a domain with a non-free finite projective module $P$, and let $Q$ be a finite projective module with $P \oplus Q \cong R^n$. This gives an idempotent matrix $A \in M_n(R)$ corresponding to $(p,q) \mapsto (p,0)$.

For each prime ideal $\mathfrak p \subseteq R$, the modules $P_{\mathfrak p}$ and $Q_{\mathfrak p}$ are free. If $S \colon P_{\mathfrak p} \oplus Q_{\mathfrak p} \stackrel\sim\to R_{\mathfrak p}^n$ is the isomorphism above and $D \colon P_{\mathfrak p} \oplus Q_{\mathfrak p} \to P_{\mathfrak p} \oplus Q_{\mathfrak p}$ the diagonal matrix $(p,q) \mapsto (p,0)$, then $A_{\mathfrak p} = SDS^{-1}$ is diagonalisable. (We can really think of $D$ as a matrix, at least after choosing bases for $P_{\mathfrak p}$ and $Q_{\mathfrak p}$.)

But $A$ is not globally diagonalisable since $P$ is not free: if $A = SDS^{-1}$ for some diagonal idempotent matrix $D$ and some invertible matrix $S$, then $S$ induces an isomorphism $S \colon \operatorname{im}(D) \stackrel\sim\to \operatorname{im}(A)$. But $\operatorname{im}(D)$ is free whereas $\operatorname{im}(A) \cong P$ is not free.

**Example.** Carrying this out for $R = \mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $P = (2,1+\sqrt{-5}) \subseteq R$ produces the matrix
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} -2 & -1-\sqrt{-5} \\ 1-\sqrt{-5} & 3 \end{pmatrix}.$$
The image contains the vectors $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} -2 \\ 1-\sqrt{-5} \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} -1-\sqrt{-5} \\ 3\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, which are linearly dependent but not common multiples of some other vector in $R^2$.

**Motivation.** If $A_{\mathfrak p}$ is diagonalisable for all $\mathfrak p \subseteq R$, then there exists an open cover $U_1 \cup \ldots \cup U_m = \operatorname{Spec} R$ such that $A|_{U_i}$ is diagonalisable for all $i$. This gives matrices $S_i \in \operatorname{GL}_n(U_i)$ such that $D_i := S_i^{-1}A|_{U_i}S_i$ is diagonal.

Assuming for simplicity that $R$ is a domain, we conclude in particular that all eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_r$ of $A$ lie in $R$, since they lie in $R_{\mathfrak p}$ for all prime ideals $\mathfrak p$. Choose some diagonal matrix $D \in M_n(R)$ with the same eigenvalues/multiplicities as $A$, and assume without loss of generality that $D_i = D|_{U_i}$ for all $i$. Then $S_j^{-1}S_i \in \operatorname{GL}_n(U_i \cap U_j)$ is a matrix commuting with $D$, giving a cocycle in $H^1(\operatorname{Spec} R,G)$, where $G = C_{\operatorname{GL}_n}(D)$ is the centraliser of $D$. This cocycle is a coboundary if and only if $A$ and $D$ are globally conjugate matrices.

Under the additional hypothesis that $\lambda_i - \lambda_j \in R^\times$ whenever $i \neq j$, a straightforward computation shows $G = \prod_{i=1}^r \operatorname{GL}_{m_i}$, where $m_i$ is the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. Thus, in this case the only obstruction is in $\prod_{i=1}^r H^1(\operatorname{Spec} R, \operatorname{GL}_n)$, leading to the example above.

But in general, $G$ need not be a flat group scheme over $R$, so the situation is considerably more complicated. For instance, if $D$ is the diagonal matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 5\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, then $G \times \operatorname{Spec} \mathbf F_3$ is the full group $\operatorname{GL}_{2,\mathbf F_3}$, so $G$ has a vertical component above $p=3$. Even in the case of a PID, it is not so clear to me what is going on...

**Remark.** If $R$ is no longer a domain, it is probably more natural to look at the centraliser of $A$ instead of $D$ (which is some sort of 'Zariski inner form' of $C_{\operatorname{GL}_n}(D)$ in the domain case, so it should have the same $H^1$). I expect there might be other global obstructions coming from the non-injectivity of the maps $R \to R_{\mathfrak p}$: perhaps there are too many global choices of $D$ to run the argument above.

You could also imagine an obstruction in $H^1(\operatorname{Spec} R, S_n)$ for globally ordering the eigenvalues in the matrix $D$, although all examples I know where $H^1(\operatorname{Spec} R, S_n) \neq 1$ also have $H^1(\operatorname{Spec} R, \operatorname{GL}_m) \neq 1$ for $m \gg 0$. (An irreducible scheme has no higher cohomology in constant sheaves, even for $H^1$ with non-abelian coefficients, so we didn't see this problem in the case above.)

Comment: Nice. If 2 implies 1, the argument shows that all finitely generated projjective modules are free. Is the converse true? If all projective modules are free, does 2.imply 1?

Comment: @Mohan thanks, your comment made clear what the key point of my construction is. Now edited, with some comments about whether this is the only obstruction.